# Components inserted into page using jquery's .load() function don't have a handle to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I am working on an assignment that uses jquery's load() function to build a single page application

index.jsp

```
<body>
  <div id="center-pane">
    <!-- JQUERY LOADS COMPONENTS HERE -->
  </div>
  <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This gets called at some point in script.js

```
$("#center-pane").load("otherPage.jsp")
```

This line exists in otherPage.jsp

```
<a class="testPrinting">Testing</a>
```

I want the contents of otherPage.jsp to be loaded into the div on index.jsp, which it does, and then have the following function execute as such in script.js

```
$(".testPrinting").on('click',function(){
    console.log("Success!");
};
```

It seems to not work because otherPage.jsp is loaded after the javascript has already been loaded, at which point the element with class "testPrinting" doesn't exist.

However, if I change the line in otherPage.jsp to this:

```
<a onclick="logToConsole()">Testing</a>
```

the console log works.

Is there any way to get this functionality to work using the jquery selector instead of the onclick?

Comment: Note the mention of delegate event handlers in the accepted answer

Comment: why do you want to load jsp with javascript?

Comment: I'm loading the jsp with javascript because on index.jsp I have toolbars that I don't want to be reloaded. So I just want to update the center component. Correct me if my thinking is wrong on this please.